# How to insert dynamically through a variable in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, database, insert, dynamic

Lets create a table first

```
create table test
(
  id number,
  name varchar2(20)
);
```

Now during insert, I want to hold the data into variable first & then dynamically pass the variable into the VALUES clause like this:

```
declare
  v_data varchar2(50);
begin
  v_data:='1,sunny';
  execute immediate 'insert into test values(v_data)';
  commit;
end;
```

But its showing some errors(Not enough values)...... plz help how to achieve this??

Comment: Try creating a :dynstmt string by doing a string operation, including the quotes for the srting value and then use EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :dynstmt. Note that this is not a good practise as it would be prone to SQL injection.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use different variables for each value

```
declare 
  v_data1 number
  v_data2 varchar2(50);
begin 
  v_data1 :=1
  v_data2 = 'sunny'; 

  insert into test values(v_data1,v_data2);
  -- Alternatively insert into test (Name) values (v_data2);
commit; 
end;
```

Comment: But my requirement is different, i have to pass the variable which holds        the value string commaseparated.

Answer (score 4):

Table test has two columns. You're only inserting one and not naming which column it is hence "not enough values".  So you need:

```
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES (data)
```

or probably better is to put in an ID:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (1, data)
```

or simply:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, data)
```

For this kind of thing though I would use a cursor rather than dynamic SQL (or even inline SQL).

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to pass values into dynamic SQL statements is with bind variables like this:

```
declare 
   v_id integer;
   v_name varchar2(50);
begin
   v_id := 1;
   v_name := 'sunny';
   execute immediate
      'insert into test (id, name) values(:b1, :b2)'
      using v_id, v_name; 
   commit; 
end;
```

That needs one variable per value.

Comment: :b1 is replaced by the string "v_id" for me

Comment: @Eildosa did you put `using 'v_id', 'v_name'`?

Comment: So you didn't follow the method in my answer, and you got a different result?  Interesting but not sure how I can help with that?

Comment: no, sorry it was ambiguous, I mean since it was not working I used the other method instead. when I use your method it puts the name of the variable in the statement not the content of the variable. || however put the content of the variable

Comment: No, it doesn't.  If that happened you did not use my code I can assure you.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach works, but you need to adjust your query a little:

```
execute immediate 'insert into test values(' || v_data|| ')';
```

so that the contents of your v_data variable are actually inserted into the string, not the value "v_data" itself.

Comment: thanx buddy...but its still showing error - ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: bind variables should be recommended, but for occasional inserts there may not be a performance penalty, although this is an opportunity for sql injection attacks.

Comment: That's because the data would need to be: '1,''sunny''' for this to work.  Best to avoid this approach anyway, as Martlark days.